# SharePoint Version is compatible with my computer

Tags: sharepoint-server, windows-server

I have a Windows server 2012 and a 32 bit operating system. Can someone please provide me with any helpful information as to what version of SharePoint I should install on my computer?

Also can you provide me the links to the installer and tutorial on the said version?

Also at some point I will have to connect my SharePoint in vb.net 2010

Comment: Not sure I understood everything, but on Server 2012 you can install Sharepoint 2013 SP1 foundation (just google it), that's free. What do you mean with "install SharePoint on my computer" ?

Comment: Windows Server 2012 is only available in 64 bit version. I guess that's what you have as an OS.

Answer (score 1):

On windows server 2012 you can install sharepoint 2013 which is the latest sharepoint version.

To install sharepoint 2013 on windows server :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/440608/SharePoint-Installation-on-Windows-Server

http://www.jppinto.com/2013/10/sharepoint-2013-installation-on-windows-server-2012/

http://www.stephensaw.me/installing-sharepoint-2013-on-windows-server-2012-part-1/

If you want to install Sharepoint 2010 check :

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12502.sharepoint-2010-how-to-install-and-configure-windows-server-2012-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: hi i already tried to download the sharepoint 2010 but nothing happens when i clicked the install prerequisites and also nothing happens when i clicked the install sharepoint 2010 but its always working properly when i click the other links

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: no errors just when i try to click the link for the installation nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server 2012 R2 is not compatible with SharePoint Server 2013 (without SP1). If you have Windows Server 2012 R2, then you must install SharePoint Server 2013 SP1. If the OS is not R2, then SP1 for SharePoint Server 2012 is not mandatory (but recommended).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the SharePoint server 2013 or SharePoint Foundation 2013 on the windows server 2012(which are fully supported).

But it is depend upon your requirement, SPF is light weight version and free but dont have full functionality i.e User Profile services etc.

On the other hand if you want o use SP server then you need to buy a license. But i am seeing you need this farm for development if that is correct then you can use the MSDN license(if you have subscription). or other option is download the trial version of server which will expired after X days.

Now How to install the SharePoint 2013 in a single farm.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262243(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262243%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

http://ahmedmadany.wordpress.com/2012/08/30/install-sharepoint-2013-on-single-server-with-sql-server/

http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2013/04/17/step-by-step-build-a-free-sharepoint-2013-lab-in-the-cloud-with-windows-azure-31-days-of-servers-in-the-cloud-part-7-of-31.aspx#.UZ-GD9Lkv90

video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SCtisok12uY

Answer (score -1):

I don't think Windows server 2012 R2 is recommended yet. SharePoint 2013 will not fully function on Server 2013 if SP1 is not installed.

"Installing SharePoint Server 2013 on a computer that is running Windows Server 2012 R2 could lead to unexpected behavior, therefore, Microsoft does not support SharePoint Server 2013 in Windows Server 2012 R2."

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2891274/en-us

http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2013/09/22/sharepoint-2013-support-for-windows-server-2012-r2.aspx

Comment: Server 2013 ? What do you mean ?

Comment: what you mean by windows server 2013, MSFT already include the windows server 2012R2 support in SP1. You need SharePoint Server 2013 with SP1 to install on windows server 2012 r2.